# Searching values from Listview

Tags: java, android

I had use onQueryTextChange() for searching text from list using BaseAdapter for ListView. Now Iam getting Null Pointer Exception while searching. So please sort it out. while searching somewhere value is not fetched from the list.

```
public class GetListView extends ListActivity implements OnQueryTextListener {
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    private static String[] data;

    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_IMG = "img";
    private static final String TAG_PRICE = "price";
    private static final String TAG_DESTINATION = "destination";

    JSONArray products = null;
    ListView lv;
    LazyImageLoadAdapter adapter;

    private String[] str;
    private String[] mPid;
    private String[] mName;
    private String[] mPrice;
    private String[] mDestination;

    final Context context = this;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent iN = getIntent();
        data = iN.getStringArrayExtra("getdata");
        setTitle(data[1]);

        productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        new LoadAllProducts().execute();

        lv = getListView();
        lv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background);
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);

        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
        //    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        // this is your adapter that will be filtered
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
            lv.clearTextFilter();
        } else {
            lv.setFilterText(newText.toString());
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == 100) {
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }


    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(GetListView.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading data.. Please wait..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(data[0], "GET", params);
            Log.d("Gellting all the list : ", json.toString());

            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);
                    str = new String[products.length()];
                    mPid = new String[products.length()];
                    mName = new String[products.length()];
                    mPrice = new String[products.length()];
                    mDestination = new String[products.length()];
                    for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        String price = c.getString(TAG_PRICE);
                        String destination = c.getString(TAG_DESTINATION);
                        String img = c.getString(TAG_IMG);

                        str[i] = img;
                        mPid[i] = id;
                        mName[i] = name;
                        mPrice[i] = price;
                        mDestination[i] = destination;


                    }
                } else {

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    adapter = new LazyImageLoadAdapter(GetListView.this, context, str, mPid, mName, mPrice, mDestination);
                    getListView().setAdapter(adapter);
                    getListView().setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background);
                }
            });

        }

    }
}
```

Error :

```
06-11 04:19:38.759: D/AndroidRuntime(1334): Shutting down VM
06-11 04:19:38.759: W/dalvikvm(1334): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4a6dba8)
06-11 04:19:38.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1334): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-11 04:19:38.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1334): Process: com.ambrogroup, PID: 1334
06-11 04:19:38.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1334): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ambrogroup/com.ambrogroup.GetListView}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-11 04:19:38.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1334):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
06-11 04:19:38.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1334):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
06-11 04:19:38.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1334):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
06-11 04:19:38.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1334):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
06-11 04:19:38.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1334):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-11 04:19:38.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1334):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-11 04:19:38.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1334):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
06-11 04:19:38.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1334):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-11 04:19:38.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1334):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-11 04:19:38.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1334):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-11 04:19:38.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1334):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
06-11 04:19:38.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1334):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-11 04:19:38.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1334): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-11 04:19:38.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1334):     at com.ambrogroup.GetListView.onCreate(GetListView.java:65)
06-11 04:19:38.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1334):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
06-11 04:19:38.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1334):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
06-11 04:19:38.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1334):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
06-11 04:19:38.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1334):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: indicate line 65 @ `GetListView`

Comment: Where is `setContentView()`?

Comment: setContentView is not needed when you use ListActivity as the parent

Comment: I am suspecting if this line is getting you proper string array? data = iN.getStringArrayExtra("getdata");

Comment: What is line 65 in `GetListView.java`?

Comment: why this error caused by onCreate(). Null pointer exception. What is missing??

Comment: you don' need runOnUiThread in `onPostExecute`

Comment: setTitle(data[1]); is line  no 65

Comment: @user3726074 indicate line 65

Comment: @user3726074 data is null. can you confirm??

Comment: in data[1] Title is receiving from Intent. When I click on search button and type, then i click again for then it cause. I think variable data after searching do not get value back in it. Am i right??

Comment: @user3726074 yes that sounds right.  The call `iN.getStringArrayExtra("getdata")` must be returning `null` in that situation

Comment: I had commented that.. but Error 06-11 05:23:02.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1457): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
occured

Comment: 06-11 05:23:02.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1457): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2